# doesnt get in the if statement javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

so I have to get the bigger salary of the average salary and to print the name of the person, but I don't get in the `if` at least the alert says so. Here is my code:

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        xDOC = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

        xDOC.async = "false";
        xDOC.load("pti_project.xml");
        x = xDOC.getElementsByTagName("person");
        alert(x.length);
        var avgsal = 11450 / x.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var salary = x[i].getElementsByTagName("salary");
            if (salary * 1 > avgsal * 1) {
                alert("1");
                var person = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name");
                document.write(person[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
        }
        document.write(avgsal);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

No clue why is this happens, it should work.

Comment: Hint, try logging `salary` in console. Check if it holds correct value

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you , it doesnt hold value .

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Hope you got the reason for giving hint and not answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How its name says, the method **getElementsByTagName()** returns a collection of objects, not their values.
Look at the example in this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765549(v=vs.85).aspx
The result of the function is iterated with a `for` loop to get each matched element and then its `xml` property is printed.
Something like:

```
(salary.length > 0 ? parseFloat(salary.item(0).xml) : 0)
```

would work for you instead of only `salary`.
This expression will check if the collection is not empty and if so will get the content of first element. Otherwise will return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to my question I needed little time , but I made it . So here is the code if somebody needs help with such type of situation :

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
xDOC=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

xDOC.async="false";
xDOC.load("pti_project.xml");
x=xDOC.getElementsByTagName("person");
var avgsal = 11450/x.length;
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
var salary=x[i].getElementsByTagName("salary");
if(salary[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue>avgsal*1)
{
var person=x[i].getElementsByTagName("name");
document.write(person[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("<br>");
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```